# Images Not Loading in XAMPP

Tags: html, xampp, image

I am writing a program that dynamically generates dice and loads the corresponding image.  Everything works, except the images never load using localhost.  Something must be wrong with my path.  Whether I use the relative or absolute path, no image loads.

The absolute path is: C:\xampp\htdocs\php6-mysql\3\die1.png

Alas, I created a most basic HTML page, and the image still doesn't load.  Any ideas? Is this a problem with XAMPP?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Here are your dice!</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <img src="die1.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set read/write permissions for each image.  I believe you can do the whole folder but if that doesnt work do each image individually.  right click(two finger mac) => get info => read and write for all of them.  reload and presto, you got images through xampp.[image]

Comment: you can have an images folder inside the project folder.  They can all be in the same, just add permissions for the images.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your image inside `htdocs`. It is the root of your page.
or this `/php6-mysql/3/die1.png` to your html `<img src` tag.

Comment: Thanks fo the reply.  The html file is located in the same folder as the image, so "die1.png" should suffice.  Nevertheless, I tried <img src="\php6-mysql\3\die1.png"> and still nothing.  Could this be an issue with XAMPP?

Comment: try to remove the first "/". You can play with the codes. Be creative.^_^ and you actually use "\" instead a "/"

Comment: wait, what is the path of the html document? you should place it to the `htdocs`

Comment: After further investigation, the path was correct.  However, Windows was appending the file type to the file name.  Thus, it was looking for "die1.png.png."  After removing ".png" from the file name and using the relative path listed in my original post, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image from online sources. For instance, you can have your pictures in dropbox and retrieve them from there.
Here is the code:

```
<a href="#"><img src="URL" alt=""></a>
```

That should help you to play around with images as you look for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

like you opened the php file after  replacing your file with dashboard from "localhost/dashboard" do the same
like:
before your file address was:
"file:///F:/download/xamp/htdocs/icons8-pavlova-100.png"
after:
"http://localhost/icons8-pavlova-100.png"
this way it will show.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is reading the file and directly adding it to the src as base64_encoded. In PHP

```
$data  = file_get_contents($path.$filename);
$out[] = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($data).'" width="100" height="100" alt="" />';
```